# Cannot delete storage blob even though I have no VMs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have removed all my Azure VMs and now I'm trying to remove a vhds container storage blob from a classic storage account. It gives me this error:

*There is currently a lease on the blob and no lease ID was specified in the request*

I have found an article that mentions this error: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/thbrown/2015/04/04/there-is-currently-a-lease-on-the-blob-and-no-lease-id/

It suggest to remove VMs. I have, beforehand. Have I messed up by deleting the VM first so now I am unable to detach the image from it? Is this a bug?

Comment: This has already been answered - look at the question linked to, which your question is a duplicate of. My answer there shows how to remove associated disks with both Classic and ARM-based storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the lease with powershell with the following command:

```
Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -Name 'mystorageaccountname' | Get-AzureStorageBlob -name 'mycontainername').ICloudBlob.BreakLease()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with classic VMs. Following approach worked for me:

1. In Azure Classic Portal, go to **Virtual Machines**, then click on **Disks**
2. Select the Disk resource you want to delete (the **Attached to** column should be empty)
3. Click **Delete**, then **Delete the associated VHD**

**EDIT:** Please ensure that you delete the **Disk Resources**! By breaking the lease and just removing the VHDs without deleting disk resources there still would remain some metadata stored and you couldn't delete the storage account if you wanted to.